# Разбить строку на значения Python

Tags: python, строки, парсер

Есть строка типа `sdd,L12,W45,H78,7cm,K,D6`

Нужно разбить на 12,45,78,7 по отдельными переменными для вставки в базу.

Задание элеметнарное..Нужно очень срочно реализовать на Python, никогда не работал в Python, спасибо

Comment: С чем у Вас конкретно возникли трудности? Решение полноценных заданий не совпадает с политикой данного сайта.

Comment: `12,45,78,7` а как же `6`?

Answer (score 1):

Не уверена, что правильно поняла вопрос, но строку на последовательность значений разбивает функция split:

```
           t=s.split(',')
```

А дальше я бы при помощи for и if проверяла, содержит ли текст число, и если да, записывала бы его в массив.

Comment: Юлия, вы в целом правы. ) Минус наверное воспитательный вам поставили, т.к. вопрос неформатный)

Comment: Я только сегодня зарегистрировалась на сайте, еще не совсем в курсе местных правил. Наверное, не буду пока ничего писать, пока совсем не заминусовали ))

Comment: ничего страшного) главное оставайтесь и принимайте участие

Answer (score 1):

Решение действительно элементарное:

- с помощью регулярки удалить все символы, кроме 0-9 и ',' (запятой)
- методом `split` разделить строку на список
- убрать из списка пустые элементы

```
import re

text = 'sdd,L12,W45,H78,7cm,K,D6'
text = re.sub(r'[^\d,]', '', text)

items = list(filter(None, text.split(',')))
print(items)
# ['12', '45', '78', '7', '6']
```